# Why is my Subnet Mask 255.255.255.255?

Tags: networking

I am connecting to Internet through my Nokia E71 on the EDGE network in India. Every time i connect to Internet my IP addess is 27.107.66.139  with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.255.  What does that means & how come a network can have a subnet mask of 255.255.255.255 ?